# Eigenvalues and Normal Modes in SHM

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, eigenvalue, normal-modes

I'm reading Symmetries part from the textbook provided by MIT OCW Physics3 8.03SC course, but have a question about the condition to find normal modes of SHM. In the book they mentioned

$S$ - symmetry matrix
$A^n$ - eigenvector
$b_n$ - eigenvalue

If $SA^n = b_nA^n$, and $b_n != b_m$ for $n != m$, then $A^n$ are normal modes.

What if some of the eigenvalues of $S$ are the same? How 
$$b_n != b_m \text{ for } n != m$$
condition affects on finding the normal modes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to asking what happens when the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to $b_n$ is not one-dimensional. Say it has dimension $k$, then we can form an orthonormal basis of this eigenspace to obtain $k$ orthonormal eigenvectors $A_1^n,\dots,A_k^n$. So these vectors are mutually orthogonal, but also then eigenspace corresponding to $b_m$ is orthogonal to the eigenspace corresponding to $b_n$ if $b_n\neq b_m$ via the standard proof, regardless of dimension of the eigenspaces.

Edit: To see this last fact, let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be normalized eigenvectors corresponding to a symmetric matrix $S$ corresponding to $b_1\neq b_2$. Then
$$
b_1\langle A_2, A_1\rangle = \langle A_2, b_1A_1\rangle = \langle A_2, SA_1\rangle = \langle SA_2, A_1\rangle = \langle b_2A_2, SA_1\rangle = \overline{b}_2\langle A_2, A_1\rangle.
$$
Since $S$ is symmetric, $b_1$ and $b_2$ are real, so we have $b_1\langle A_2, A_1\rangle = b_2\langle A_2, A_1\rangle$. However, $b_1\neq b_2$, which implies that $\langle A_1,A_2\rangle=0$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: So you mean that the b_n != b_m condition makes eigenvectors orthogonal, which can be normal modes in the system?

Comment: Edited my answer to add a proof of this fact.